# How do I denormalize the sklearn diabetes dataset?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

There is a nice [example of linear regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html) in `sklearn` using a diabetes dataset.

I copied the notebook version and played with it a bit in Jupyterlab. Of course, it works just like the example. But I wondered what I was really seeing.

- There is a chart with unlabeled axes.
- I wondered what the label (dependent variable) was.
- I wondered which of the 10 independent variables was being used.

So I played around with the nice features provided by ipython/jupyter:

```
diabetes.DESCR

Diabetes dataset
================
Notes
-----
Ten baseline variables, age, sex, body mass index, average blood
pressure, and six blood serum measurements were obtained for each of 
n = 442 diabetes patients, as well as the response of interest, a
quantitative measure of disease progression one year after baseline.

Data Set Characteristics:
:Number of Instances: 442
:Number of Attributes: First 10 columns are numeric predictive values
:Target: Column 11 is a quantitative measure of disease progression one year after baseline
:Attributes:
:Age:
:Sex:
:Body mass index:
:Average blood pressure:
:S1:
:S2:
:S3:
:S4:
:S5:
:S6:

Note: Each of these 10 feature variables have been mean centered and scaled by the standard
deviation times `n_samples` (i.e. the sum of squares of each column totals 1).
Source URL:
http://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~boos/var.select/diabetes.html
For more information see:
Bradley Efron, Trevor Hastie, Iain Johnstone and Robert Tibshirani (2004) 
"Least Angle Regression," Annals of Statistics (with discussion), 407-499.
(http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/LARS/LeastAngle_2002.pdf)'
```

From the Source URL, we are led to the original [raw data](https://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~boos/var.select/diabetes.tab.txt) which is a tab-separated unnormalized copy of the data. It also further explains what the "S" features were in the problem domain.

- Interestingly, sex was one of [1,2] with a guess as to what they meant.

But my real question is whether there is a way within `sklearn` to determine

- how to denormalize the data in sklearn?
- Is there a way to denormalize the coefficients and intercept so that one could
  express the fit algebraically?

or is this just a demonstration of linear regression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to denormalize data without any information about the data prior to the normalization.  However, note that the `sklearn.preprocessing` classes `MinMaxScaler`, `StandardScaler`, etc. do include `inverse_transform` methods ([example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.inverse_transform)), so if this were also provided in the example it would be easy to do.  As it stands, as you say, this is just a regression demonstration.